# failed to load derailed using mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a Rails 5 App (5.1.rc2) which is using mongoid instead of mysql. On my real production server (heroku), the app is running properly. But when I try to load it

```
env RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec derailed exec perf:allocated_objects
```

I get this output:

```
Booting: production
bundler: failed to load command: derailed (/Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/derailed)
URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme mongodb does not accept registry part: <MYURL>
```

MY URL : `mongodb://username.password@HOST1:PORT`, `HOST2:PORT`, `HOST3:PORT`

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
here is a more detailed stacktrace:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme mongodb does not accept registry part: username:password@cluster-shard-00-00-asdf.mongodb.net:27017,cluster-shard-00-01-asdf.mongodb.net:27017,cluster-shard-00-02-asdf.mongodb.net:27017 (or bad hostname?)


    /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/generic.rb:206:in `initialize'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:219:in `new'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:219:in `parse'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:38:in `initialize'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:268:in `new'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:268:in `resolve_url_connection'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:256:in `resolve_hash_connection'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:231:in `resolve_connection'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:141:in `resolve'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:161:in `block in resolve_all'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:160:in `each'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:160:in `resolve_all'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:70:in `resolve'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/core.rb:48:in `block in <module:Core>'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `class_eval'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `append_features'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/base.rb:291:in `include'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/base.rb:291:in `<class:Base>'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/base.rb:275:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/stringex-2.7.1/lib/stringex/acts_as_url/adapter/active_record.rb:18:in `require'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/stringex-2.7.1/lib/stringex/acts_as_url/adapter/active_record.rb:18:in `orm_class'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/stringex-2.7.1/lib/stringex/acts_as_url/adapter/base.rb:52:in `loadable?'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/stringex-2.7.1/lib/stringex/acts_as_url/adapter.rb:17:in `block in load_available'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/stringex-2.7.1/lib/stringex/acts_as_url/adapter.rb:15:in `each'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/stringex-2.7.1/lib/stringex/acts_as_url/adapter.rb:15:in `load_available'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/stringex-2.7.1/lib/stringex.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-slug-5.3.3/lib/mongoid/slug.rb:2:in `require'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-slug-5.3.3/lib/mongoid/slug.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:105:in `require'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:105:in `rescue in block in require'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block in require'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
  /Users/jan/RubymineProjects/gn2016/config/application.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/derailed_benchmarks-1.3.2/lib/derailed_benchmarks/tasks.rb:19:in `require'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/derailed_benchmarks-1.3.2/lib/derailed_benchmarks/tasks.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/derailed_benchmarks-1.3.2/lib/derailed_benchmarks/tasks.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:216:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `each'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `invoke_prerequisites'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/derailed_benchmarks-1.3.2/bin/derailed:41:in `exec'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/derailed_benchmarks-1.3.2/bin/derailed:92:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/derailed:22:in `load'
  /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/derailed:22:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: are you sure that's a valid way to do the URI? The InvalidURIError is pretty telling so there's definitely something wrong with your URI.

Comment: yes. My URI also works in production. I've updated my question (added my stacktrace)

Comment: Are you running rbenv 2.4.1 in both production and development or are you running a different version of ruby locally?

Comment: Also, just trying to help, but I can't get this to work in MRI, either. Works: `URI('mongodb://username:password@host1.com:123')
 => #<URI::Generic mongodb://username:password@host1.com:123>`. Doesn't work: `URI('mongodb://username:password@host1.com:123,host2.com:456')
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?) mongodb://username:password@host1.com:123,host2.com:456`

I'm using MRI 2.4.0

Comment: Ah, I was using the wrong class... `parser = URI::RFC2396_Parser.new; parser.parse 'mongodb://username:password@host1.com:123,host2.com:456'` throws your error: `URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme mongodb does not accept registry part`